# how to rearrange the elements in an array?

Tags: arrays

please give an algorithm that will rearrange all the elements in an array such that none of them are in their previous positions.will reversing of the array elements work?(I will swap the middle element with the first(or the last) element if the length of the array is odd.

Comment: take first element off the front of the array; re-attach it on the end. Or move the last element to the front. Either way, it answers the question (except for arrays with one or zero elements, but there isn't any answer to the question for them)

Answer (score 0):

Shift them one position to the left, moving the first element to the end.

The method you outline in your question would also work.